# Cannot load overwritten scss in Nextjs producation only

Tags: linux, next.js, sass, deployment

I was trying to deploy my nextjs 13 appdir application to the producation. but got a problem with bootstrap overwritten scss dosen't load on producation after running `yarn run build` and `yarn start` here are the screenshots in development server and producation server.

1. producation server
   [image]
2. development server
   [image]

Thanks in advance